# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'context.uiTheme.toolbar' ) ('react-native-material-ui')

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to use [react-native-material-ui](https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui) library's toolbar. But I keep getting one error or another in the process. I have been stuck on this for a long time now. 
My `index.android.js` looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,AppRegistry, View } from 'react-native';
import { Toolbar } from './node_modules/react-native-material-ui';


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
pageContainer: {
    flex: 1,
},
});


export default class Reminder_react extends Component {
   render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.pageContainer}>
            <Toolbar leftElement="arrow-back" centerElement="Icon Toggle" />

        </View>
    );
   }
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Reminder_react', () => Reminder_react);
```

I get no error on the terminal but the phone screen lights up like red light district. This is the error.

[image: react native error stack]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think for material-ui to work you need to apply the theme. From [the docs](https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui#usage) that I understood you should do something like this.

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '../react-native-material-ui';

//...

return (
  <ThemeProvider>
    <View style={styles.pageContainer}>
      <Toolbar leftElement="arrow-back" centerElement="Icon Toggle" />
    </View>
  </ThemeProvider>
);
```